# Do we use "the" before an adjective? For example, in "(the) religious perspective"

Tags: articles

> Many people have interpreted this short story from **the** religious perspective.

or

> Many people have interpreted this short story from religious perspective.

Answer (score 1):

It's a count noun, so if the question is about articles in particular, you have to do one of two things.

1. Use an article with a singular noun:

> Many people have interpreted this short story from ***a*** religious perspective.
>   Many people have interpreted this short story from ***the*** religious perspective.

2. Do not use an article, but make the noun plural:

> Many people have interpreted this short story from religious ***perspectives***.

Note that it is possible to say *the religious routes* if there are multiple religious routes and many people have tried *all* of them. However, this seems unlikely.

Which specific approach you take is up to you, based on the exact meaning you're trying to convey.

---

Note that you could also use a singular *or* plural noun with a pronoun rather than an article.

For instance:

> Many people have interpreted this short story from ***my*** religious perspective(s).
>   Many people have interpreted this short story from ***your*** religious perspective(s).
>   Many people have interpreted this short story from ***their*** religious perspective(s).

Again, however, it would depend on if any of these made sense in the particular context.

Comment: Does using  “religious perspective” indicate speaking “in general” and using it with “the” indicates (1) - speaking about specific religious perspective or (2) - considering it a specific class or type other than secular perspective for example?

Comment: @GamalThomas I would be disinclined to think of *perspective* as a mass noun in this construction. It would be different if the sentence were something like *I need to get some perspective*, where the sentence indicates that different sense.  This sentence reads to me more like there are several different perspectives or types of perspectives, so it is countable. It's parallel to *I took [an / the] easy route(s)*, where there are several different easy routes and you take just one or a few of them.

Comment: Thanks for  your clear answer but why the “religious perspective” seemed to you as a countable noun in the first place ?

Comment: @GamalThomas It's not so much *religious perspective* that's countable, but *perspective*. However, there *are* multiple religions, which are countable. If you can ask *which* religion, then it's something countable...

Answer (score 0):

The appropriateness of an article is determined solely by the noun and its use in context.  Even festooning it with adjectives does not change the noun.

When in doubt, remove  the adjectives to consider.